# Tomcat server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to write a simple login page web application in a maven project in eclipse IDE. I have included Maven dependency for mysql-connector as follows :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>8.0.15</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But whenever I am trying to run the server I am getting the error that Tomcat server failed to start. However when I change the scope of the dependency from compile to provided as follow

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>8.0.15</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

the tomcat server runs just fine but when I am trying to call fetch values from database I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
     at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
     at com.myfirstApp.checkDB.checklogin(checkDB.java:17)
     at com.myfirstApp.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:40)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
     ...
```

I am unable to understand the proper flow of how maven uses the dependency, why i am getting the class not found error and why the server is unable to start when the scope is compile.

I read a previous answer and tried running the code with dependency scope as "provided" and including the jar file in the tomcat server lib folder but still got the same class not found error.

Edit 1: I am getting the following error when the scope is set to compile

[Tomcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52vFJ.png)

and when the scope is set to provided I am getting an error at the first line of the following code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
```

Edit 2 
The error I am getting while starting the server with scope as compile

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a1a3478]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@7a1a3478]
   ...
```

The full error report can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/iejy2bNe)

Comment: The scope should stay as `compile`. Probably the problem is somewhere else. When you say: _I am getting the error that Tomcat server failed to start_, what is the error that you get?

Comment: It is likely an issue with your MySQL DB.

Comment: It is likely an issue with your MySQL DB. You have to implement name, location, UN and PW for the DB. You also have to define the driver and its location. How you do that depends on your project setup. If you use Spring you should look for the application.properties file and you should find a  line like
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
If it is a simple JDBC application you have to create a new instance of the Driver object, probably something like:
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Comment: @AlexSomai  MySQL database is running fine when I am trying to access it from cmd in windows. I have edited the question for details about the line where I am getting the error

Comment: there should be an exception shown in the console - can you post it here?

Comment: @benji2505 Updated my question

Comment: My best guess is that the answer is very similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154815/tomcat-failed-to-start-component